# click handler not working on frequently reloading div

Tags: javascript, onclick, reloading

This content div keep on reloading to display realTime data, due to which onClick event is not triggering. Please suggest a alternative

```
function () {
  function render() {
    content.empty()
    content.addCass('test').append(
     $('<div>').text('content goes here')
    ).on('click', () => {
       $('this').hide()        
       return false
    })
  }
var content = $('<div>')
return render()
}
```

Comment: Does your webpage really slows down handling this real time data ? The event callback should trigger even if with a significant delay .

Comment: @khan Its dont slow down its refresh the cotent every sec, due to its rapid render click event not triggering